# Can I access the redux dispatch directly from inside an action creator by requiring it?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

Inside a redux action creator, is it reasonable to simply require the redux store with `require('path/to/store')` in order access `getState()` and `dispatch()` given that it's a singleton?

Comment: are you wanting your action creator to dispatch it's action to the reducer?

Comment: Yes. I'd likely do a combination of getting state and then potentially dispatching.

Comment: You're hard-coding a creator to specific store. You cannot reuse it with another store or test with dummy store. This defies the purpose of using Redux.

Comment: I'm able to use jest to ensure I can make use of a dummy store for testing, Hard-coding to a single store doesn't seem like an issue if I only ever have a single store. Is there some other issue I'm missing that I'd encounter?

Answer (score 3):

No, please don't do that - [importing the store directly is an anti-pattern](https://redux.js.org/faq/storesetup#can-or-should-i-create-multiple-stores-can-i-import-my-store-directly-and-use-it-in-components-myself).

Use the [`redux-thunk` middleware](https://github.com/reduxjs/redux-thunk) instead, as it's specifically intended for this use case.